# Minecraft suddenly stops working?

Tags: 12.04, windows, wine, minecraft

So, I have Minecraft on Ubuntu 12.04.  It is a Windows program, but I was able to use Wine Windows Program Loader to get it to run.  Everything was working fine and dandy earlier today.  But, later, when I tried to get it to run, I got an error saying "Bad Format" and "There is no Windows Program configured to open this type of file."

What would cause it to randomly stop working?

EDIT:  I remember that, earlier today, it started up and began updating--then the computer froze and I had to reboot.  Now it won't work.

Comment: No, this doesn't help. I have both Java OpenJDK Java 6 & 7 installed, but when I attempt to open it with either of those, it just sits there.  Doesn't open or respond or anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is a universal JAR file for minecraft avaliable for download, so you wouldnt have to use WINE. I think you would have to right click on it and open it with the JRE you have downloaded.

Universal JAR file download link: http://www.minecraft.net/download

EDIT: I do not know what may have caused that, maybe something went wrong with WINE